# Office suite windows lag when dragging them around

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office

This doesn't happen with any other programme, but Office has been acting up weirdly on my PC and getting slower and slower. Reinstalling never helped. Can't figure out why. Anyways, whenever I drag a Word, excel or other office window around, my coursor and window lag behind a lot. It really feels like I am online with 200+ms ping. Any ideas what could cause this?

I have the newest updates for Windows 10 and Office 64bit (1709/1711).

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the exact version of Office. What you have now won't be the latest version when this question is seen in the future.

Comment: Outlook 2013 and 2016 both lag when dragged on a rather powerful (dual Xeon, 64GB RAM) computer. There's no noticeable lag on Word or Excel, but Outlook, definitely. I've never spent much time trying to figure out the issue.

Comment: Edit your question to indicate what build of Office 2016 you have installed

Comment: I'm not seeing the version of Office, just the Windows build version...?

Comment: @Tomhawk Please provide the information I requested.  Feel free to delete your unnecessary comments

Comment: Tomhawk, you can add Tags for the specific Office version(s) you're having this issue with.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a 'gaming mouse' with an adjustable polling rate, set it as low as it allows via its software. Typically this is 100 Hz.

I have never come across another fix, nor has Microsoft showed interest in fixing it.

Comment: Initially my mouse polling rate was 500 and dragging MS Office programs was unbearable.  Dialing the polling down to 250 fixed the problem.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this problem myself with a fresh Windows 10 installation. It affected only Excel of all my Office 2013 suite, no other apps. I use both a Bloody Hand gaming mouse (wired USB) and a Logitech wireless mouse on this laptop depending on where I am. I noticed the problem while using the wired USB mouse. I uninstalled the Logitech Setpoint software and the problem went away.

Comment: And, it's back again, without the Logitech software installed. I'll keep looking, I guess.