# Word window lags when mouse polling rate 500 or above

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word

When I set the polling rate to 333 Hz, everything works fine, but at 500Hz Word and Excel, start lagging when I draw the window around.
It also only happens if I'm inside the document.
I tried out a different mouse and the issue still persists.
I am now using a G700s.
It does not happen in all programs eg:Chrome
Windows version: 1709
Office version: 1710

but NOT Chrome, explorer, task manager and so on

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Office suite windows lag when dragging them around](https://superuser.com/questions/1274623/office-suite-windows-lag-when-dragging-them-around)

Comment: why do you need such a high polling rate? No human can have that fast response whatsoever

Comment: @phuclv Actually, that's entirely accurate.  No human has a **reactive** reflex speed (as in those for which the stimulus one is reacting to is completely unanticipated), but for **proactive** reflex that is well within the scope of human capabilities.  E.g., in the FGC gaming community, players consistently utilize mechanical inputs constrained within a window of a single frame.

Answer (score 0):

I search on reddit and find out this case, I advise you try it.

“it has to do with the mouse and the USB polling frequency

With a Logitech MX518 with 125Hz I had no problems whatsoever. Ever since I switched to a Logitech G502 with 1000Hz these Office applications started to lag when dragging. You can reproduce this by changing the mouse frequency in the mouse drivers from e.g. 1000Hz to 125Hz. The option is called "Report Rate" in the Logitech Gaming Software. Dunno about other vendor's mouse drivers.

In the end I think it's probably a f*ckup between the high polling frequency of the mouse and therefore high update rate of the cursor and Windows' GUI VSync as well as Excel/Word refreshing the content of the window.

*edit2* Refreshrate of the monitor does NOT matter. So it's solely the high USB polling rate that's causing this.”

https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/5fkyxt/windows_10_lag_with_word_window_dragging/